# Error In Insering Date In Mysql Using PHP : 000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, date, web

Am Working With The MVC Structure And I Have An Error When I Type A Date in a TExt Area 
In That Form YYYY-MM-DD    Ex: 2014-09-17

It Insert In Mysql LIke This 0000-00-00

This is The View

```
   <html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>

                    <div class="register">
                <form action="InterventionController.php" method="POST"> 
                    <h1> Ajouter Une Date Pour L'intervention: </h1>
                    <input required="required" name="Date" class="input-group-addon" type="text" placeholder="Date Sous Forme :  yy-mm-dd ">


                    <input required="required" class="btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajouter L'intervention">


                </form>

            </div>



    </body>


</html>
```

and This Is The Controller

```
     <?php


if($_POST){

        if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == "Ajouter L'intervention" ){

      $data['Date']  =      $_POST['Date'];



       try {
           include 'models\AddInterventionModel.php';
            new AddInterventionModel($data);
           } catch (Exception $exc) {

               echo $exc->getMessage();
           }
        header("location:index.php?page=Demande_Inter");


    }



                    }
 else {
                        include 'Login.php';
 }




?>
```

And This Is The Module

```
<?php


class AddInterventionModel {



   private $Date;

   private $cnx; 

   function __construct($data) {

        if(is_array($data)){

            $this->setData($data);
           }
           else 
           {
               throw new Exception("Error Data Should Be An Array");

           }


           // Connect To Database
           $this->connectToDb();

           //Insert User Data 

           $this->AddInterventionModelF();

   }

   private function setData($data)
   {
       $this->Date      = $data['$Date'];



   }

   private function connectToDb() {
       include 'models/Database.php';
       $vars = "include/vars.php";
       $this->cnx = new Database($vars);

   }

   function AddInterventionModelF ()

   {
       $query = "INSERT INTO `intervention` (`ID_I`, `DATE_I`) VALUES('','$this->Date')";

       $sql = mysql_query($query);

       if($sql){
           echo 'Added Sussecfully';


       }
       else
       {

           throw new Exception("Error : not Added");
       }

   }

   function close(){

       $this->cnx->close();
   }

   }
```

Comment: Few issues: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi / PDO instead; path of `include()` should use slash instead of backslash; after `header('Location: ');`, remember to use `exit`; last, don't post all the codes here, post related lines only please.

Comment: `Mname` contains date?

Comment: When do you set `$this->Date` exactly ? And Texts With Capital Letters At The Beginning Of Every Word Are A Pain. Really.

Comment: Sorry Sirs  . i am just stressed those days (i should give a report for the school plus the application and i am really late ps : am just begin with php this 40 last day and i didn't learned from school so please forgive me for my stupid mistakes   )

i have edited the code
Thanks for your fast response

Answer (score 2):

First, you named the `input` "Mname", but you are calling `$_POST['date']` in the controller (so you have to change 'Mname' in 'date'.

Second, in the Module you are verifing if the date is an array, but the date should be a string.

Finally, consider to use this

```
$dateString = $_POST['date'];
if (!empty($dateString)) {
    $date = new \DateTime($dateString);
    $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
}
```

and then in the mysql query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `intervention` (`ID_I`, `DATE_I`) VALUES('','".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i')."')";
```

Comment: I Have edited the code sorry for my mistakes .... sorry but i didn't understood your response and i didn't know how to implement your solution in my code

Comment: Did you copy the code that you have posted without understanding it? Specify what you do not understand.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) ... i didnt understood this DateTime($dateString);

and The  $date->setTime(0, 0, 0);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.construct.php
http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.settime.php